# Regex to match url's domain

Tags: regex

Depending on whether I'm using a headed or headless server to test my web app, the domain name of my local development server changes:

When headless:

```
http://test.host
```

When headed:

```
http://127.0.0.1:22401
```

I'm trying to create a regex that will match both of these. It seems simple but I've been getting in a real mess, help appreciated.

```
http://test.host/need/to/not/match/this/part
http://127.0.0.1:22401/need/to/not/match/this/part
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this regex also which uses a negated character class(`[^...]`),

```
(?<=:\/\/)[^\/\n]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fP2bR6/6)

Answer (score 1):

here you go

**Regex**

```
(?<=:\/\/)(.*?)(?=\/)
```

**Test string**

```
http://test.host/need/to/not/match/this/part
http://127.0.0.1:22401/need/to/not/match/this/part
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - 1. [7-16]  `test.host`
- MATCH 2

  - 1. [52-67] `127.0.0.1:22401`

online [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fP2bR6/2)

---

if you do not want to match the port :22401

here is the update to match more scenarios

```
(?<=:\/\/)(.*?)(?=\/|:|\n)
```

this will also be able to match the string `http://test.host`

demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/fP2bR6/4)

Comment: I know the result should be the same, but I would personally use this instead: `(?<=\/\/)([^\/\s]*)(?=\/)`

Comment: i would use `(?<=:\/\/)[^\/]*`

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's close but it doesn't match the two forward slashes? http://regex101.com/r/zS5wN8/1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understood you correctly. Are you looking for this:

```
(http\:\/\/(?:test\.host|127\.0\.0\.1\:22401))
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uM3wM0/1)

In case you want to cut off `http://`, you can use:

```
(?:http\:\/\/(test\.host|127\.0\.0\.1\:22401))
```

Both regexes are based on the assumption that you want to have these fixed strings.